# Is there an operation to extract number at a specific digit position from an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm new here and I'm sorry if this is too basic or impossible, I have no idea. I'm a developer trying to code and I found myself looking for a number at a specific position in an integer, for example, extracting the hundreds digit the integer: 8521 (in this case, 5).

My question is if there is an operation/equation that would allow me to extract a number from a position in any integer.

Comment: There are lots of ways.  For example if you can do integer division and remainder, divide by $100$ (dropping the remainder) and then take the remainder on division by $10$ (perhaps with negative numbers take the absolute value first)

Comment: Not exactly maths, but you can convert the number to a string and then ask for the $n$-th character

Comment: Lol.. question closed. Classic StackExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the $10^k$ digit from a number n, we can calculate:

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^k} \right\rfloor \mod 10
$$

Or, in code: `(n / 10**k) % 10` (using an integer division which ignores the remainder)

In your example with 8521, we'd have $n=8521$ and $k=2$. So the digit would be:

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{8521}{10^2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 85.21 \right\rfloor = 85 = 5  \mod 10
$$